# Tweepy does not return includes object using StreamingClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using `tweepy` `4.10.1` to fetch Tweets using `StreamingClient`, but I am unable to load any `media` info or even `includes` object itself. I have tried the similar code using `get_tweet()` method and `media` and `includes` were received fine.

The code:

```py
class TweetPrinter(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.includes)


streaming_client = TweetPrinter('bearer-token')

streaming_client.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("from:xxxyyy"))

streaming_client.filter(tweet_fields=['author_id', 'created_at'],
                        media_fields=['preview_image_url', 'url'],
                        expansions=['attachments.media_keys'])

print(tweet.includes)
```

I am receiving following error:

```py
raise AttributeError from None
```

When I use the same tweet id with `get_tweet()` method, I can retrieve `media` from `includes` fine.

```py
client = tweepy.Client(config.BEARER)

ID = 'xxxxyyyy'

tweet = client.get_tweet(ID,
                         tweet_fields=['author_id', 'created_at'],
                         media_fields=['preview_image_url', 'url'],
                         expansions=['attachments.media_keys'])

print(tweet.includes)
```

---

According to Google, official docs and FAQ, I have tried all recommended steps I found

- [Why am I not getting expansions or fields data with API v2 using Client?](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.6.0/faq.html#why-am-i-not-getting-expansions-or-fields-data-with-api-v2-using-client)
- [tweepy.StreamingClient.filter](https://Why%20am%20I%20not%20getting%20expansions%20or%20fields%20data%20with%20API%20v2%20using%20Client?) allows `media_fields`  and `expansions`
- [Tweepy does not return url media field while using Twitter API v2 methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293546/tweepy-does-not-return-url-media-field-while-using-twitter-api-v2-methods)
- [tweepy.StreamingClient.on_includes](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.9.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.on_includes) this valides that `includes` should be available

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT

I have discovered that using `on_data()` is the proper way how to retrieve **all** data from tweet. It covers all `tweet`, `includes` and other objects.

So the proper code should looks like this:

```py
import orjson

class TweetPrinter(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        # Received as bytes, needs to be loaded by json (I use orjson)
        raw_data = orjson.loads(raw_data)
        print("data")
        print(raw_data.get('data', None))
        print("media")
        print(raw_data.get('includes', None))
```

---

#### Deprecated solution

The `TweetPrinter` class should contain function to handle when `includes` received like this:

```py
class TweetPrinter(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.data)

    def on_includes(self, includes):
        print(includes)
```

Thanks to [this](https://medium.com/@dipankarmedhi11/streaming-tweets-using-twitter-v2-api-tweepy-456350d046b2) article, it helped me to find the proper solution :)

Comment: For me this command in Depr. solution print(tweet.data)
gives only {'edit_history_tweet_ids': ['1631286987025170432'], 'id': '1631286987025170432', 'text': ''}
In other wods tweet_ids and tweet.text.. how other values can be included?

Comment: @josifoski 
Have you been able to find a solution to this issue? If yes, please share it with me